# C# Serial Port Receive and Acknowledge

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm back again with a little project I am stuck on at the moment, trying to receive and then acknowledge the receipt to get the next set of data from the COM1 device.

Basically the device is a Motorola MC1000 hand held barcode scanning device, the software that is on it, is linked to this program which no longer works but sends the data output via serial, and I have managed to get the data out manually by connecting to the port and then manually sending "%0" to the device to output all the data from memory.

So far, I have coded a program to connect to the com device, open the com port, and receive the buffer information, but I need to send an automatic acknowledgement to get all the data out.

The data is in the format of Barcode    Qty.

Here is my code so far:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
      {
          // Add this variable

          string RxString;
          SerialPort ComPort = new SerialPort();  

          public Form1()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
          }

          private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              ComPort.PortName = Convert.ToString(cboPorts.Text);
              serialPort1.PortName = ComPort.PortName;
              serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;

              serialPort1.Open();
              if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
              {
                  buttonStart.Enabled = false;
                  buttonStop.Enabled = true;
                  textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
              }
          }

          private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
              {
                  serialPort1.Close();
                  buttonStart.Enabled = true;
                  buttonStop.Enabled = false;
                  textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
              }

          }

          private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
          {
              if (serialPort1.IsOpen) serialPort1.Close();
          }

          private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
          {
              // If the port is closed, don't try to send a character.

              if(!serialPort1.IsOpen) return;

              // If the port is Open, declare a char[] array with one element.
              char[] buff = new char[1];

              // Load element 0 with the key character.

              buff[0] = e.KeyChar;

              // Send the one character buffer.
              //serialPort1.Write(buff, 0, 1);

              if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) // enter key  
              {
                  serialPort1.Write("%0");
                  //textBox1.Text = "";
              }
              else if (e.KeyChar < 32 || e.KeyChar > 126)
              {
                  e.Handled = true; // ignores anything else outside printable ASCII range  
              }
              else
              {
                  serialPort1.Write(e.KeyChar.ToString());
              }


              // Set the KeyPress event as handled so the character won't
              // display locally. If you want it to display, omit the next line.
              //e.Handled = true;
          }

          private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              textBox1.AppendText(RxString);
          }

          private void serialPort1_DataReceived
            (object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
          {
              RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting() + "\n";
              this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
          }

          private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              string[] ArrayComPortsNames = null;
              int index = -1;
              string ComPortName = null;

              //Com Ports
              ArrayComPortsNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
              do
              {
                  index += 1;
                  cboPorts.Items.Add(ArrayComPortsNames[index]);
              } while (!((ArrayComPortsNames[index] == ComPortName) ||
                (index == ArrayComPortsNames.GetUpperBound(0))));
              Array.Sort(ArrayComPortsNames);

              if (index == ArrayComPortsNames.GetUpperBound(0))
              {
                  ComPortName = ArrayComPortsNames[0];
              }

              //get first item print in text
              cboPorts.Text = ArrayComPortsNames[0];
          }

          private void cboPorts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {

          }
      }
  }
```

I just somehow need to output this all automatically.

Comment: Could you reduce the wall of code you have there to just show where the problem lies?

Comment: You are not using ReadExisting() appropriately.  It just returns whatever happens to be available, usually only one or two characters.  Appending \n is of course not correct.  Consider using ReadLine() instead, setting the SerialPort.NewLine property to whatever character is sent last.

Comment: I will give this a try, see if that makes any difference